# Is it possible to convert a WinForms app into a COM server?

Tags: .net, winforms, com

We have a .NET 4.5 WinForms application that would need to be operated through COM by a non .NET app.

Is it possible and if yes, where should I look for achieving this?

Comment: .NET does not have great support for an out-of-process COM server.  You should not try unless you know what you're doing.  Doesn't exactly sound like it.

Comment: You could try UI automation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible by using the .NET framework in general. It doesn't mind which kind of UI framework you are using on top (WinForms, WPF).

Here is a nice [guide to COM interop via .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163494.aspx). I think that should you get started.